# Moving Bootcamp partition to another drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp, migration

I don't know how sketch this is.

I currently have Bootcamp with Windows 7 on my internal along with my Snow Leopard. I'm moving to a bigger harddrive. I'm reinstalling Snow Leopard but I would like to keep my Bootcamp. How do I migrate the data from one drive to another? Any suggestions?

I'm not willing to spend money on this

Comment: Thanks for the writeup. Not using compression on the disk image was the key to getting it to work. I am not sure why having compression on kills the restore. @Xster writeup: http://tech.xster.net/tips/moving-bootcamp-partition-to-new-drive/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Winclone](http://www.twocanoes.com/winclone/) is a free tool that will make and restore images of your Windows drive. (Alt links: [Cnet Download](http://download.cnet.com/Winclone/3000-2242_4-172338.html), [Softonic](http://winclone.en.softonic.com/mac/download))

Comment: I'd never heard of that, but a quick skim of the linked URL seems like this is exactly what the OP is looking for. Upvoted. @user26453: Nice work. You might want to set your username to something a little less default, though. :)

Comment: nice stuff. However, I haven't really heard from people who made this work with a Windows 7 64 bit flawlessly yet. I'll volunteer to guinea pig myself

Comment: Excellent! Winclone worked flawlessly. Required settings are write as dmg and uncompressed. It takes a really long time to restore but shorter than it would have taken me to reinstall all the stuff

Comment: I wrote my process at http://tech.xster.net/tips/moving-bootcamp-partition-to-new-drive/
Thanks guys

Comment: Would this be a good way to change the partition size while you're at it?

Comment: I looked at the product page, and it looks like the answer to my question is "yes".

Comment: @brainjam, yup, I changed the partition size while I was at it.

Comment: Although Winclone has been discontinued, it's still available from [Softonic](http://winclone.en.softonic.com/mac/download).